# database connectivity issue using netbeans with phpmyadmin(wamp)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Getting this message in exception handling:

> java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName

Correctly included in libraries mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
[image]

Previously using the same configurations with mysql server and that was working perfect. Recently I uninstalled that and set up WAMP in windows, and since ten unable to connect. The piece of code being used is:

```
Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName","root","");
```

Things I have tried yet is using:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

though issue is still the same. Looking for help.

Comment: please post more code about the connection to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Remove the `mysql-connector-java.jar` library from your project and re include it.
2. After including Right click on your project and select `Clean and Build`. (screenshot showing some error in `form1.java` file fix the errors and try build)
3. And use

   ```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   ```

   I hope this might be helpful.